# Change a string using jquery selector and javascript regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

All I want to do is replace the letter "y" with the letter "i" in all s with a certain class. I'm not sure why my script isn't working. I know the selector is working because I can swap the method to something like hide() and it works. I also can assign the value of the replace() into a variable, and that variable shows the correct substitution. So I'm boggled why the combination of the two isn't working...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
function() {
    $("span.certain_class").text().replace(/y/g, "i");
}
);
</script>';
```

EDIT: I need to clarify that I need to do this to multiple spans throughout the page. Remember that the text() method stacks up all the texts of each span... so something like this won't work:

```
$("span.certain_class").text($("span.certain_class").text().replace(...))
```

Each span will end up with a mess of the other span's text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span.certain_class').each(function() {
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/y/ig, function(s) {
            return (s === 'Y' ? 'I' : 'i');
        }));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Slightly off-topic follow-up question: 
I know that the /i flag will make the regex search case-INsensitive, but is there an elegant way to make the replacement correspond to the original case?

Comment: Very cool! I didn't realize you could pass a function as the second parameter of replace(). I just want to make sure i understand one thing: where does the "s" parameter of the function get assigned?

Comment: `function(s)` <-- there (line 3).  That will be set to whatever the regex matches.  In this case that would be `y` or `Y`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! I have a related question, but it's getting off the original topic, so I started a new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921913/i-want-to-use-javascript-replace-to-add-html-tags-but-its-returning-them-as

Answer (score 0):

A typo in first line!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../jquery.min.js"></script>
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[working demo!](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/ab47c)

or if you want to change it directly to the same span, use

```
    $("span.certain_class").text($("span.certain_class").text().replace(/y/g, "i"));
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/ab47c/2

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("span.certain_class").text(
    $("span.certain_class").text().replace(/y/g, "i")
  );
```

Your script does correctly replace all the "y"'s with "i"'s but it doesn't assign the value back to the dom element.

Answer (score 0):

The `text()` function only gets the contents. But with you're current piece of code you don't replace the contents.

```
var replacement = $("span.certain_class").text().replace(/y/g, "i");
$("span.certain_class").text(replacement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your solution works but you don't do anything with the result. Do you want to replace the text inside the div? Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var elm = $("span.certain_class");
        var text = elm.text().replace(/y/g, "i"); // Get current text and replace y to i
        elm.text(text); // Set new text
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) called without arguments only returns the element's inner text, and since strings are immutable in Javascript, your call to `replace()` will create a new string that's immediately forgotten.

You can pass a function to `text()` in order to build the new value from the previous one:

```
$("span.certain_class").text(function(index, currentText) {
    return currentText.replace(/y/g, "i");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
var replaceSpan = $("span.certain_class")
replaceSpan.text(replaceSpan.text().replace(/y/g, "i"));
```

You need to pass a string to the `.text()` method. All you're currently doing is grabbing the text of `span.certain_class` as a string (`.text()`), performing the replace (`.replace(..)`), but then not doing anything with the resulting string.