# I want to use Javascript replace() to add html tags (but it's returning them as strings)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have a simple javascript function which replaces the "y" character within a any span.certain_class with an "i":

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('span.certain_class').each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/y/ig, function(s) {
        return (s === 'Y' ? 'I' : 'i');
    }));
});
```

});

The problem I'm having is that I want to wrap the replaced character with a span:

```
<span>i</span>
```

When I do this, the browser prints out the tags as strings, instead of parsing them as HTML code.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(this).html($(this).text().replace........
```

That will make the result parse as HTML rather than plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).html(...)` instead of `.text()` to set the contents. You might also want to use `html` when reading the contents to replace (depends on what they are in your scenario).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just change the first call to `text()` to a call to `html()`:

```
$(this).html($(this).text().rep...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span.certain_class').each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/y/ig, function(s) {
            return (s === 'Y' ? 'I' : 'i');
        }));
    });
});
```

Change your $(this).text to $(this).html